# Initializing Mongo DB for Spring Boot Test

Tags: spring-boot, spock, spring-data-mongodb

I'm building a Spring Boot application that uses Spring Data Repositories with MongoDB.  I'm attempting to create a Spock functional Spec to test my repository but I can't figure out the appropriate way to initialize the Mongo DB in preparation for testing.  So far I have tried the following:

1. Do Nothing - This resulted in the same database being used from test to test with my tests failing after.
2. Drop the database before testing - This resulted in the indexes being lost and me being unable to test my unique indexes.

Here's what I was doing with dropping the database:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyApp, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader)
@ActiveProfiles('test')
class UserRepositoryTest extends Specification {

    @Shared
    boolean mongoReset = false

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository

    void setup() {
        if (!mongoReset) {
            mongoTemplate.getDb().dropDatabase()
            mongoReset = true
        }
    }

}
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to use something similar to the data.sql method provided with JPA repositories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We usually recommend to rather use the repository to wipe the database (i.e. calling `userRepository.deleteAll()`). Dropping the database has the downside of wiping all the indexes that might have been created during context bootstrap time.